# c# parse string (without timezone) to DateTime, taking DST into account

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, timezone, dst

I've read many SO articles, but I don't seem to be able to find a good answer to the problem. Posted suggestions include functions that convert dates to and from strings more then once, concatenating bits on the end and it all just seems... messy

So to the problem:

We have servers around the world. All servers run in their own local time and keep logs with time entries that are local to the server. Some servers are in DST observing areas, others arent

Suppose I have these strings from a log: *2013-01-01 12:34:56,  2013-07-01 12:34:56*
And I know that this server is in New York so it's UTC-5 or UTC-4 when DST is in operation

And I have the same strings from a log on a server in Hong Kong, where DST does not apply and the time zone is +8

What I'm after is a block of code where I can tell it:

- Here is a string representing a time
- Here is the timezone the string is from
- Daylight Savings should apply if relevant

And the code will parse the string into a DateTimeOffset, where the offset is adjusted according to DST if the time being parsed is DST relevant

For example:
NY server log says "*2013-01-01* ..." DST **does NOT** apply to this date in JANUARY so the date parsed should be:
12:34:56 in new york time, a.k.a 17:34:56 in UTC (because it's -5, no DST)

NY server log says "*2013-07-01* ..." DST **DOES** apply to this date in june so the date parsed should be:
12:34:56 in new york time, a.k.a 16:34:56 in UTC (because it's -4, with the DST)

HK server, both date times parse to 04:34:56 UTC

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the UTC-times of the time logged in the different log files you will need to know the names of the local time zones. Then you can use the [`DateTimeOffset`-struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) [`TimeZoneInfo`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) to calculate the UTC-times:

```
public DateTime ParseAsUtc(string logDate, string timezoneName)
{
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneName);
    var localDate = DateTime.Parse(logDate);
    var offset = new DateTimeOffset(localDate, timeZone.GetUtcOffset(localDate));
    return offset.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;
}

ParseAsUtc("2013-01-01 12:34:56", "Eastern Standard Time"); //01.01.2013 17:34:56
ParseAsUtc("2013-07-01 12:34:56", "Eastern Standard Time"); //01.07.2013 16:34:56
ParseAsUtc("2013-01-01 12:34:56", "China Standard Time");   //01.01.2013 04:34:56
ParseAsUtc("2013-01-01 12:34:56", "China Standard Time");   //01.07.2013 04:34:56
```

Comment: See my comment on Jon Skeet's answer.  Same applies here.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I'd *strongly* recommend that you change the system to log in UTC everywhere. It'll make your life much simpler.

If you're *really* stuck with what you've got, you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) with a `DateTimeStyles` of just 0 (the default). That will give you a value with a `DateTimeKind` of `Unspecified`, which is what you want. (It's not UTC, and it's not local to the machine doing the parsing.)

You can then use [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378.aspx) (with the right time zone for that log) to work out the offset, and create a `DateTimeOffset` from the two together.

As a completely biased aside, you could also change to use the [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project I maintain, which will allow your code to be much simpler to understand :)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the local time may be ambiguous if the log does not store some indicator of whether or not the DST shift has happened on "fall-back" transitions.  There's no way around that.  All the reason to log in UTC time, or record the offset in the log.

Comment: Very valid point; I suppose the only way I can tell if the clock on the server has updated with a DST change backwards (thereby realising an ambiguous date) is to keep a memory of the previous line's date/time and see if this current line's datetime has jumped backwards.. Hmmm

Comment: I'll also take a look at Noda Time, thanks Jon.. I was initially put off because I hadn't read your great blog post or any of the supporting documentation (and maybe I'm getting old and becoming reluctant to change my spots :D )

Comment: Looking at it now, I think I'd use a ZonedDateTime(local, zone, offset) constructor but the puzzling part is what I'd put for offset, because I don't necessarily know it.. In NY it'll be -4 or -5 depending on the local, but all I know at this time is "offset should be adjusted for dst true/false" not the offset itself. I know why Noda is asking me for the offset, because it wants to check that I know what I'm talking about and infer the DST active/inactive state from my claimed offset.. Whereas I'm looking for a solution that is the other way round, i think...

Comment: @CaiusJard: Don't call the constructor directly - call `DateTimeZone.AtLeniently` or `LocalDateTime.InZoneLeniently` - or the strictly version. Those do the mapping for you.